# Is there a better way to write these ansible tasks using jinja?

Tags: ansible

I have this task in my playbook:

```yaml
- name: service check
  block:
    - name: service check | check port 843 is connected.
      shell: |
        netstat -n | grep 843 | grep ESTABLISHED |wc -l
      register:  check_843_connection_count
    - debug: msg="{{inventory_hostname}} (PASS) {{check_843_connection_count.stdout}} connections to port 843"
      when: check_843_connection_count.stdout | int > 0
    - debug: msg="{{inventory_hostname}} (FAIL) {{check_843_connection_count.stdout}} connections to port 843"
      when: check_843_connection_count.stdout | int <= 0
  when:
    - stype is defined and stype == "foo"
  tags: mmr_check_843_estiablished
```

I think there is probably a way I could combine the two `debug` tasks.  Maybe something like:

```yaml
- debug: msg="{{inventory_hostname}} {{check_843_connection_count | int >0 ? '(PASS)' : '(FAIL)'}}  {{check_843_connection_count.stdout}} connections to port 843"
```

But, obviously, the above has syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jinja being a Python templating language, the [inline if](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#if-expression) would write quite the same as in Python.
*Mind that Ansible is written in Python, so, it also makes all the sense*.

So, you could write this debug task:

```yaml
- debug: 
    msg: >-
      {{ inventory_hostname }} 
      ({{ 'PASS' if check_843_connection_count.stdout | int > 0 else 'FAIL' }}) 
      {{ check_843_connection_count.stdout }} 
      connections to port 843
```